# Serve React App from Express Server Err - not a supported stylesheet MIME type

Tags: reactjs, express

So I followed the documentation from the [creat-react-app-docu](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment) and I can not figure out how to serve my react-frontend via express. In the docs it is stated as follows:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(9000);
```

But my project structure looks like this:

```
--root
      |
      backend
             |
             src
                |
                index.ts (My express config)
      |
      web
         |
         build (Production build of my react app)
```

So I had to adapt the config in my **index.ts** like this:

```
// Present Frontend view
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../web')));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../web/build', 'index.html'));
});
// Start the server
server.listen(3000, () => console.log('BYOD is listening on port 3000!'));
```

But the error I am getting is that is:
Refused to apply style from `'http://192.168.145.135:3000/BYOD/static/css/main.74ea495e.chunk.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`.

My Question is now: Am I doing something conceptionally wrong? How can I solve this issue?

## Update

So I figured out that that the urls in the index.html (within the build folder) has some wrong urls e.g.:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/BYOD/favicon.ico"/>
```

instead of just:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>
```

These urls are automatically inserted by **CRA**. How can I prevent to load false public-urls into the index.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Solution approach is to add in my frontend dir (react-project) a .env file and set explicitely the following:

```
PUBLIC_URL=/
```

My question now is there a better solution or is my project architecture completely messed up? **Im extremely curios for advices!** Thanks in advance!